# C data structure, variables

Tags: c, pointers, variables, structure

Sorry for noob question

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct  s_test
{
    int         head;
    char        *end;
}               t_test;
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
   t_test a;
   t_test *b;
}
```

What is different between `a.head` and `b->head`?. Why can't I type `a->head` or `b.head`?. I know `b` is a pointer which holds an address of a variable type `t_test`.

Comment: `->` dereferences the pointer on the left, then adds the offset to the member on the right.

Comment: You can't type `a->head` because `a` is not a pointer. And you can't type `b.head` because `b` does not represent a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `b->head` is just convenient syntactic sugar for doing `(*b).head`.

You have to dereference a pointer to a struct before you can use the dot notation on it, that's why you cannot do `b.head`.

The reason why you cannot do `a->head` is that `a` is not a pointer, so it cannot be dereferenced. The dereferencing operator `*` only makes sense for pointers.